# IDA debugging SSE intrinsics

Tags: ida, hexrays

Whenever I hover over a SSE variable, e.g.:

`correct = tmp_corr;`

Which are both declared as `__m128` IDA shows them as a string of bytes, e.g. "\x00\x00..."  sometimes even weird characters...

Is there anyway to make it display it as 4 floats instead or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bit lazy to answer this myself so here we go.

Basically, it seems to display the registers just fine (XMM), so if you press TAB while on Psuedo Code it will take back to where it points to in assembly display, and then you can hover on the XMM register and it will display it nicely.