# View XMM registers in IDA Pro while debugging

Tags: ida

How can I view the XMM registers in IDA Pro?

While debugging, I can only view the default registers and eflags. Is there a way to view the XMM registers, xmm0 to xmm7?

Thanks.

Comment: It appears there's been a way since IDA 5.7: http://www.hexblog.com/?p=127 I'm not on a machine to check where that resides, but if no one else steps in here before you're able to check, look for that window somewhere (perhaps you have to enable it in settings somewhere to show). Additionally, the following two posts may or may not prove useful for you: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/accesssing-xmm-registers-in-idapython and https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12623/ida-debugging-sse-intrinsics

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. We need to enable that window using the options: Debugger -> Debugger Windows -> XMM Registers. The same can be done to view other registers like FPU or MMX registers as well.